# Bind to the number of objects

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to understand how I would create a binding or computed property that is the number of objects I have. I can get the number (I think) via:

```
App.MyObject.all().get("length")
```

When I create a controller property with that inside a function it doesn't update as more objects are downloaded.

```
numOfMyObjects: function(){
  return App.MyObject.all().get("length");
}.property()
```

Right now I have this in my ApplicationController, but it just shows 0.

I'd like to know how to do this for all of the objects and then also for a filtered set of objects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Ember on which properties it should observe to fire the `numOfMyObjects` method. For example:

```
numOfMyObjects: function(){
  return App.MyObject.all().get("length");
}.property('myArray.length');
```

However, this won't work in your case because you've got `App.MyObject` in your controller itself, instead you want to be instructing the appropriate route which model(s) the controller should represent.

This way you won't actually need to create a computed property, because you'll have access to the `model` in your Handlebars.

Please see the JSFiddle I've put together as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ESkkb/

The main part of the code lies in the `IndexRoute`:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Cat.find();
    }
});
```

We're telling the `IndexController` that it should represent all of the cats. And then once we've done that, we can display the cats in our view, or in our case, the number of cats:

```
Count: {{length}}
```

Comment: My problem is that I'm never displaying all of the `MyObject`s at one time. They are being display, in parts, across multiple views.